# Cannot set $_SESSION variable when two synchronous ajax processing calls are sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have what might be a tricky question.

I am working on a form where it verifies a couple things on submit, using `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from submitting if something went wrong. The issue here is that it sends multiple ajax requests at the same time, which seems to stop the php (which is processing the AJAX call) from modifying the $_SESSION variable.

I have determined this by changing the jquery ajax calls to process synchronously, allowing the $_SESSION variable to be changed.

My question is this: is there a way to allow the ajax calls to happen synchronously while allowing the $_SESSION variable to be modified during the process of those calls? I realize that the `async:false` for an AJAX call is deprecated, and obviously not the best solution.

Due to what each call does, it is not possible to combine the functionality of these two calls, although each call does not take long at all to process.

Example jquery code to explain how I am making these AJAX calls (some redaction and simplification, obviously):

```
$("#form-id").on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/url/to/processing.php',
        async:false, //fails without setting to false
        ...
    });
});
...
$("#form-id").on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/url/to/processing2ThatSetsSession.php',
        async:false, //fails without setting to false
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concat the calls, to run one call after the other has ended.

I'll do it this way:

```
function ajaxPost(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url
        ...
    }).done(callback);
}

$("#form-id").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Always stop the event
    // Do one ajax call and wait for the data
    ajaxPost('/url/to/processing.php', function(data) {
        // Do things with returned data and call the next ajax
        ajaxPost('/url/to/processing.php', function(moredata) {
            // Do something with moredata
            // If everything is fine, re-post it but this time do not catch the event
            $("#form-id").off("submit").submit();
        });
    });
});
```

You can add your own logic to show your error message in any callback and not continue with the next one.

With this I'll do an special method for multiple ajax form validation:

```
// This function will get an array of objects and
// do an ajax call and process the data, one after another
function multiAjax(calls, callback) {
    var call = calls.shift();
    if (call) {
        var url = call.url;
        post(url, function(data) {
            var error = call.process(data);
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            } else {
                multiAjax(calls, callback);
            }
        });
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

// This is the array of objects that multiAjax will process.
// You can add or remove elements to your likings, without modifying
// the submit event callback
var ajaxArray = [{
    url: '/url/to/processing.php',
    process: function(data) {
        if (data.isWrong()) {
            return "The data is wrong";
        }
    }
}, {
    url: '/url/to/processing.php',
    process: function(data) {
        if (data != "OK") {
            return "The data is not OK";
        }
    }
}];

// Now listen for the submit event
$("#form-id").on('submit', function(event) {
    // Always stop the event
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do multiple ajax calls in one function call.
    // Because the array is mutated inside multiAjax() (yeah, bad design but I've
    // done this fast as an example), we slice() the array to get a new one
    multiAjax(ajaxArray.slice(), function(error) {
        if (error) {
            // Show the error received
        } else {
            // submit the form the same way above
            $("#form-id").off("submit").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

This is all untested code, but you get the point.

Comment: looks like a great idea! I will definitely look into this. Thanks!

Comment: @Snappawapa Glad you liked it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If one form submission is making two posts to the same PHP server, you should rethink the architecture instead of building complicated workarounds.

I would POST to a single PHP script that will do everything you need in the backend.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/url/to/all-processing.php',        
    ... // send all the data needed by all processes
});
```

On the PHP side: **all-processing.php**

```
session_start();
require_once './process1.php';
require_once './process2.php';
```